# How do I clear clipboard contents on Samsung Galaxy Tab S?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-rom, copy-paste

I use a Samsung Galaxy Tab S tablet running the official non-rooted ROM based on Android 4.4.2 KitKat. Sometimes i copy-paste sensitive data (like passwords etc) that i would prefer to disappear from the clipboard once i'm done using it. So i was looking for a way to clear clipboard contents on demand.

I've tried looking for existing answers to this question, but most of them share the same misconception: that clipboard can only hold a single element, and one should copy something new into it to clear what's been there before.
It's not true in my case. For example, look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8yvR.png) from my device, it shows something i would call a "clipboard panel" that contains eight of the most recently copied elements. This panel appears to be the only way to actually clear the clipboard contents, i.e. the 3rd party apps like Clipper or Clipboard Contents can only clear their own copies of clipboard but never the system one.

Unfortunately, getting access to the clipboard panel is a somewhat convoluted process for me. It can be accessed via Samsung Keyboard (which i don't use in favor of SwiftKey) or via some other apps, but not in a straightforward way.

So my question can be summed up to two items:

1. Is there a way to clear the clipboard contents other than with help of the clipboard panel?
2. If not, then is there a way to access the clipboard panel directly, e.g. via a shortcut on the Home screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long click on the search bar (from google for example) as if you were pasting ...pick the clipboard...pick edit...delete what you want by clicking the trash can on the images or material.

.

Comment: First off, there is no "clipboard" when long tapping on a search bar. Second of all, I stated in my question that I know several 3rd party apps that allow accessing the clipboard, but that's not an approach that i find viable when dealing with a system resource like clipboard. So, unfortunately, the solution you're offering is not feasible.

Comment: that answer works great on my S5 Galaxy running 4.4.2

Comment: @Semisonic, I think what zeke is aiming you towards is the text controls that appear when you are in a text field. Search box is just a convenient one. I saw a similar forum post that suggested - Tap any text field to start text entry. Tap the cursor to evoke the slider under the text. Tap the slider to evoke editing controls, including the clipboard icon. Does that work? If so, maybe we can just edit this since zeke was pretty close.

Comment: @Saiboogu, my point is that in my particular case the text controls that appear when working with text fields don't include any "clipboard icons". To illustrate that please see the screenshot taken on my device - http://imgur.com/GNcMfm8. Like I said earlier, in some 3rd party apps the text controls do include the clipboard icon, but that's by no means a default behavior.

Comment: Understood. Not having a Samsung device I couldn't double check if he was on the right course or not, and I saw a possible point of confusion to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S and I clear my clipboard like this:  go to Google (the website, not the quick search bar) long click in the search bar, choose clipboard and touch clear, then confirm. This is pretty much what the others said, so I think that you are trying to use the quick search bar that is on the tablet home screen instead of actually using the website search bar.  This should work

Comment: I honestly don't know why, but this just doesn't work. I opened the Google website in both Chrome and Firefox: Chrome only shows "paste" popup on long tap, while Firefox opens a clipboard panel on top of the screen, but only the "paste" icon is present. Maybe my tablet is cursed, I don't know =/.

Comment: Okay.  Another way you could try is long click in the Web address bar.  You'll want to long tap after it turns blue.  A small group of icons pop up, like :  select all,  cut, copy, etc.  You can swipe them to the left and there should be a clipboard icon.  Click clear, confirm, then you're done.  Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions:

1. Go into text message, type in your phone number so that if you accidentally send it, it goes only to you.
2. Click on the empty message box →  click the little blue triangle → then click clipboard. All pictures will be lit up now, along with any copied text.
3. Simply long click any picture and select delete. It took me a while messing with my phone to figure it out, but this one actually works.

Comment: As you probably noticed, my device is not a phone. It's a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

when you go to paste and you get the little clipboard panels at the bottom of your screen you'll have two buttons press the edit button and little locks and trash cans will appear over each one of your panelsPresti press the trash can buttons to delete that particular panel

Answer (score 0):

I just open up a Samsung app, like s planner (calender), and select a random date to put a "note" in. Then I long press in the title/note area and the paste/clipboard icon shows. I go to clipboard and delete all. I had the same issue as you and no clipboard showing on things like my browser. I have the same tab s as you do.