# Is there a system level way of emptying the clipboard?

Tags: system, copy-paste

I have a question about how clipboards are cleared in Android.
Now I know about the conventional methods of clearing the clipboard like rebooting the device, using third party apps, manufacturer modifications. Putting those aside, I would like to know of a way to clear the clipboard that is device/manufacturer agnostic and works with **all android** versions, assuming the device is **non-rooted**.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no 'clear the clipboard' button built in to Android. You'll need to download a third-party app.

Comment: @Josh How about in root?

Comment: You'll still need to download and install something - assuming you're happy with that, I doubt you need root to clear the clipboard, since it could be done just by selecting a space character and pressing 'copy'. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kodholken.clipboardcleaner) seems like it might do the job, and [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/how-do-i-clear-clipboard-contents-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-s) may be relevant.